# Variance of $W=e^{\frac{X}{4}}$

Tags: probability

If $W=e^{\frac{X}{4}}$, and we have a gamma distribution with $\alpha=4$, $\beta=2$, $\mu=8$, and $\sigma=4$, how would one find the variance of $W$ using the moment generating function for gamma distributions?

So far I have started with $M_{X}\left(t\right)=\left(1-\beta t\right)^{-\alpha}$, and I know that taking the first and second derivative of this will allow me to find the mean and variance, but I don't know how to apply this to $W$. All feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb E\left[e^{tX}\right] = M_{X}(t)$

Comment: Also $Var(Y)= E[Y^2] - E[Y]^2$

Comment: and $\left(e^k\right)^2=e^{2k}$

Comment: So would I put $e^{\frac{Xt}{4}}$ in place of $t$ in $\left(1-\beta t\right)^{-\alpha}$?

Comment: No.  For example you want $\mathbb E\left[e^{0.25\, X}\right]$ and you know $\mathbb E\left[e^{tX}\right]$.  So just use $t=\cdots$?

Comment: Would you use $t=0.25$?

Comment: Yes  - now try the variance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mgf of Gamma distribution is
$M_X{t}=E(e^{tx})=\bigg(1-\dfrac{t}{\alpha}\bigg)^{-\beta}$

we have

$t=\frac{1}{4}$

$E(e^{\frac{x}{4}})=E(W)=\bigg(1-\dfrac{1}{4\alpha}\bigg)^{-\beta}$

$t=\frac{1}{4}$

$E((e^{\frac{x}{4}})^2)=E((e^{\frac{x}{2}}))=\bigg(1-\dfrac{1}{2\alpha}\bigg)^{-\beta}$

Substitute values  in $V(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$to get the desired result.